# The terminology of "ordinary least squares"

Tags: statistics, regression

I understand the math of OLS. I am just wondering what does the terminology "ordinary" mean? Is there any "non-ordinary" least squares regression model?

Comment: I don't pretend to know much about any of these, but Wikipedia lists as generalizations [weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares), [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares), [partial least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression), [total least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares), [nonlinear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares), [nonnegative least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares), ...

Comment: So "ordinary" least squares just means the simplest/most straightforward least squares?

Comment: *Simple linear regression* (one independent variable) is a simpler form of *ordinary least squares*

Comment: And *averaging* (no independent variables) is even simpler